# Help with writing test class for simple Apex soql query

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, code-coverage, code

I know similar questions have been asked before, however, I cannot find an example that would lay out how to test my query online.

I am trying to roll out a lightning component that queries a custom object in order to show a table on the dashboard.

This is the class:

```
public class ActivityController {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<SCALE_Activity__c> getActivities() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Description__c, DueDate__c, Case__r.Name, Client__r.Name, AssignedTo__r.Name, Case__c, Client__c, AssignedTo__c, Type__c, Status__c
    FROM SCALE_Activity__c
    WHERE Status__c != 'Closed'
    ORDER BY DueDate__c ASC];
  }
}
```

More info if needed:

The component:

```
<aura:component controller="ActivityController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="activities" type="List" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <lightning:card title="All Due Activities" footer="View All Activities">

  <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--fixed-layout">
    <thead>
      <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
          <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="ID">ID</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Due Date">Due Date</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Reference">Reference</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Type">Type</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Description">Description</div></th>
                    <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div></th>

          <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Assigned To">Assigned To</div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.activities}" var="result">
        <tr>
            <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!result.Name}"><a href="{!'/lightning/r/SCALE_Activity__c/'+ result.Id + '/view'}">{!result.Name}</a></div></td>
          <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!result.DueDate__c}">{!result.DueDate__c}</div></td>
          <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="Reference">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!result.Case__r.Name != null}">
                    <a href="{!'/lightning/r/Case__c/'+ result.Case__c + '/view'}">{!result.Case__r.Name }</a>
            </aura:if> 
            <aura:if isTrue="{!result.Client__r.Name != null}">
                    <a href="{!'/lightning/r/Client__c/'+ result.Client__c + '/view'}">{!result.Client__r.Name }</a>
            </aura:if> 
          </div></td>
          <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!result.Type__c}">{!result.Type__c}</div></td>
          <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!result.Description__c}">{!result.Description__c}</div></td>
             <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!result.Status__c}">{!result.Status__c}</div></td>
            <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!result.AssignedTo__r.Name }"><a href="{!'/lightning/r/User/'+ result.AssignedTo__c + '/view'}">{!result.AssignedTo__r.Name }</a></div></td> 
        </tr>
      </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
  </table>
        </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

The Controller:

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {      
    // Fetch the account list from the Apex controller   
    helper.getActivityList(component);
  },

})
```

The helper:

```
({
  // Fetch the accounts from the Apex controller
  getActivityList: function(component) {
    var action = component.get('c.getActivities');
    // Set up the callback
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
     component.set('v.activities', actionResult.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

Everything is working as it should in the Sandbox, however, I cannot figure out the correct code to test for code coverage and to get above 75% in order to deploy.

I 'adopted and changed' most of the code from Trialhead challenges. I do understand the code, however am stuck with Test the class.

I understand that I have to write a class that creates dummy data, runs the query, and compares the output to the input but am not able to produce that code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Vert smart post tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Create the data.. it's pretty straight forward

```
Client__c client = new Client__c();
client.Name = 'Client Name';
insert client;

Case__c ca = new Case__c();
ca.Name = 'Case Name';
insert ca;

User u = new User();
u.Name = 'Guessing assigned to is a user';
insert u;

SCALE_Activity__c sa = new SCALE_Activity__c();
sa.Name = 'Scale name';
sa.Description__c = 'Description';
sa.DueDate__c = date.today(); 
sa.Case__c = ca.ID;
sa.Client__c = client.ID;
sa.AssignedTo__c = u.ID;
sa.Type__c = 'Type';
sa.Status__c = 'Status';
insert sa;

Then call your query

List<SCALE_Activity__c> saList = ActivityController.getActivities();

//Assert
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Some more required fields were needed to fill with your above code (which you could not have known) - but it works now. Got 100%